# Why doesn't the ::after show?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to switch between two images with keyframes, but I want them to come in by sliding either from the left or the right. The ::before image shows up but the ::after image doesn't show up at all. Here is the link to my css https://gist.github.com/wiafe/73246883a0f608274715

```
.macbook {
    max-width: 760px;
}

.macbook:before {
    content: url(../images/application-screen.png);
    position: relative;
    left: 32px;
    top: 157px;
    transform: scaleY(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    animation: c3 8s linear infinite;
    z-index: 1;
}

.macbook:after {
    position: relative;
    content: url(../images/glass-screen-2.png);
    transform: scaleY(1.155) scaleX(0.999);
    bottom: 730px;
    left: 33px;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: c5 6s ease-in infinite;
    z-index: 2;
}

.macbook img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 333px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes c3{

  0% {opacity: 1; left: 0;}
  25%{opacity:1; left: 25px;}
  50%{opacity: 1; left: 50px;}
  70%{opacity: 0; left: 70px;}
  90%{opacity: 0; left: 90px;}
  95%{opacity: 0; left: 95px;}
  100% {opacity: 0; left: 100px;} 
}

@-keyframes c5{

  0% {opacity: 0; }
  25%{opacity: 0;}
  50%{opacity: 0; }
  70%{opacity: 0; }
  90%{opacity: 1; }
  95%{opacity: 1; }
  100% {opacity: 1; } 
}
```

I'm trying to stick with CSS to do this, as my jquery is not that strong. But if there is a way to do it in jquery please, send me in that direction, thanks!

Comment: please include your code in the question not only in a link.

Comment: Can you create a live testcase and include your code please: http://jsfiddle.net/ , http://jsbin.com/, http://codepen.io, or use the snippet editor here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: you need to add a prefixed version of animation

Comment: `:before` & `:after` needs absolute positioning if you use `left` or `right` as position, so the actual element needs relative position to position the before & after.
AND they need dimension as is display: block, width & height to show.
AND you better use background-image instead of content, still you need content: ''; for :before & :after to work